# Cyclic Subgroup?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

For $U(16) = \{1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15\},$ is there a simple way to find $m \in U(16)$ such that $|m| = 4$ and $|\langle m\rangle \cap \langle 3\rangle| = 2$ and $m$ is unique without listing everything out? The operation is $m*n = mn (mod16)$

Comment: I assume $U(16)$ is what I'd call $(\mathbb Z/16\mathbb Z)^\times$.

Answer (score 1):

By the conditions, you must have $m^2\in\langle 3\rangle$. Which elements of $\langle 3\rangle$ have order $2$ (like $m^2$ should)? One square root of that element is alrady in $\langle 3\rangle$, so you find $m$ - the "other" square root - by multiplying with the "other" square root of $1$.